# Can't RedirectToAction("RedirectToDefault") in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, roles

I'm following [this tutorial](http://techbrij.com/custom-roleprovider-authorization-asp-net-mvc) using MVC 5. But I cannot return `RedirectToAction("RedirectToDefault")`; it just stays at form login, and whether true or false password not happened

```
public ActionResult RedirectToDefault()
{
    String[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();

    if (roles.Contains("Administrator"))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
    }
    else if (roles.Contains("Dealer"))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dealer");
    }
    else if (roles.Contains("PublicUser"))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "PublicUser");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

in MyRoleProvider class

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    using (RoleAccessEntities objContext = new RoleAccessEntities())
    {
        var objUser = objContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AppUserName == username);
        if (objUser == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            string[] ret = objContext.Roles.Select(x => x.RoleName).ToArray();
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try `return Redirect("/Home/RedirectToDefault");` and it works fine.

use full address "/controller/action" in redirect.